# Compare array and return the value if true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two arrays

```
ArrayA = ["exampl@gmail.com", "example@techsolutions.net", "test@topgear.com"]
ArrayB = ["TopGear","Gmail", "Tech Solutions", "Google", "Facebook", "Exxon"]
```

Now what I want to do is if `ArrayA` includes any of the values present in `ArrayB`, it should return that value. I know for a single entry, i can use the `include?` method. Also I thought of looping one array into another, but that doesnt seem right, running into wrong amount of loops.

So how do I compare two arrays here and return the value from `ArrayB` if returned true?

For example, when `ArrayA` and `ArrayB` are compared. The output in an array could look like something

```
ArrayC = ["Gmail", "Tech Solutions", "TopGear"]
```

Because the email in `ArrayA` matched the content of `ArrayB`.

Hope it makes sense.

Note: The number of elements in the array is not limited to what is shown in the example above. It can be many more elements like that in the array in the future.

Thanks. any help is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayA = ["exampl@gmail.com", "example@techsolutions.net", "test@topgear.com"]
ArrayB = ["TopGear","Gmail", "Tech Solutions", "Google", "Facebook", "Exxon"]

Hash[ArrayA.map{|i| [i,ArrayB.find_all{|j| i.include? j.downcase }]}]
#>> {"exampl@gmail.com"=>["Gmail"], "example@techsolutions.net"=>[], "test@topgear.com"=>["TopGear"]}
```

*EDIT:*

```
ArrayA = ["exampl@gmail.com", "example@techsolutions.net", "test@topgear.com"]
ArrayB = ["TopGear","Gmail", "Tech Solutions", "Google", "Facebook", "Exxon"]

ArrayA.flat_map{|i| ArrayB.find_all{|j| i.include? j.delete(" ").downcase } }.uniq
#>> ["Gmail", "Tech Solutions", "TopGear"]
```

Comment: I have updated my question with what sort of output I am looking. Sorry for updating late, please take a look :)

Comment: maybe add `.uniq` at last will be better

Comment: @leonhart I am also thinking like that. But *OP* didn't mention about anything like that,but I will add that. and I am done.

Answer (score 2):

The simple case of finding the intersection is:

```
ArrayA | ArrayB
```

The naïve algorithm for finding the *matching* intersection according to your example is:

```
ArrayA.select do |e|
  ArrayB.each_with_object( e.downcase )
    .reduce( false ) { |a, (e, o)| a or o.include? e.downcase }
end
# => ["exampl@gmail.com", "test@topgear.com"]; Tech Solutions hase space in it
```

Better algorithm is possible using suffix trees, but that's only advantageous if your arrays have more than 1000 elements each. This is a bit tricky to demonstrate, because Ruby gems catering to suffix trees are hard to find. But for demo purposes, one can always do `git clone git://github.com/respan/ukkonen-ruby.git`, then `cd` into the directory, and run `irb` there. Afterwards:

```
require './ukkonen'
tree = SuffixTree.new ArrayA.join; nil
ArrayB.select { |e| tree.contains? e.downcase.delete ' ' }
#=>["TopGear", "Gmail", "Tech Solutions"]
```

Please note that while my desire would be to construct a *generalized suffix tree* for `ArrayA`, such Ruby code has not been published afaik, so I am using an imperfect hack with `ArrayA.join`.

Comment: This probably a nice trick. But my thick brain could not catch the point. please help me to understand.

Comment: There is a method `#|` defined on arrays, meaning intersection (as in set intersection). Another operator is `#&`, meaning union. They operate by calling in succession `#hash` and `#eql?` for the array elements to detect element equality.

Comment: Humm that I understand *Sir* but `Array#|` how helpful in this post,not clear to me. But you talked about *suffix trees*. please elaborate that taking into the account array has 1000 elements.I don't want to miss that algorithm you just suggested. please state here. :))

Comment: `+1` for introducing me to that *Gem*.

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the two arrays is the only way. It's not like there exists some magic function out there that can compare two arrays in linear time.

It also looks like you want to do more than just compare two strings. That doesn't make it any easier.

Comment: What you say holds in general. But in this particular case, we have arrays of strings, and suffix trees will go long way, to roughly `O n.log(n)` where n the size of the compared array.

Comment: ah i see. thanks for your input here. Understand better now

Answer (score 1):

If the email check is the critical problem, i think this code will give a better performance (do not need a nest loop), but this is not a common solution.

```
Hash h = {}
ArrayB.each{|x| h[x.delete(" ").downcase] = 0}
ArrayA.each{|s|
    m = p(/.*@([^\.]+)\..*/).match(s);
    h[m[1]] += 1 if(m && h[m[1]]) 
}
ArrayC = [];
h.each{|k,v|  ArrayC << k if v > 0}
```